# Lotus Notes:Reading Replication History by Code

Tags: java, replication, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Is there any possible way to write a code to read replication history of any database/application in Lotus Notes.

The solution be in any language, I just need a little start as to where to look for it and how to start.

Any help will be great!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can read it via the Notes C API.  I found a post with some [sample code](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/96e67b880e693734852577c500790efd?OpenDocument) that may help.